# Function not callable anymore after one try

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, callable

I'm coding a function right now which has a really weird problem. When I define the function `Psi(t)` and call it to be plotted, it works fine. But, when you call it again to be plotted, it sends an error `'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. When you click play (on Jupyter notebook) on `Psi(t)` to define it again then call it to be plotted, it works fine again. You'd have to define it again if you wanna change a parameter then plot `Psi(t)` again. I don't know if it's with the code or the software that I use for python (VS code). Anyhow, here's the code:

```
# Constants
m = 9.109e-31           # mass of electron in kg
L = 1e-8                # length of box in m
hbar = 1.0546e-34       # hbar in J/s
x0 = L/2                # midpoint of box
sigma = 1e-10           # width of wave packet in m
kappa = 5e10           # wave number in 1/m
N = 1000                # number of grid slices

def psi0(x):
    return np.exp( -(x - x0)**2/(2*sigma**2) )*np.exp(-1j*kappa*x)

#Discrete sine transform
def dst(y):
    N = len(y)
    y2 = np.empty(2*N,float)
    y2[0] = y2[N] = 0.0
    y2[1:N] = y[1:]
    y2[:N:-1] = -y[1:]
    a = -np.imag(rfft(y2))[:N]
    a[0] = 0.0

    return a

#Inverse discrete sine transform
def idst(a):
    N = len(a)
    c = np.empty(N+1,complex)
    c[0] = c[N] = 0.0
    c[1:N] = -1j*a[1:]
    y = irfft(c)[:N]
    y[0] = 0.0

    return y

x_n = np.zeros(N, complex)
xgrid = range(N)

for i in range(N):
    x_n[i] = psi0(i*L/N)

alpha = dst(np.real(x_n))
eta = dst(np.imag(x_n))

def Psi(t):
    k = np.arange(1, N+1)
    energy_k = (k**2*np.pi**2*hbar)/(2*m*L**2) 
    cos, sin = np.cos(energy_k*t), np.sin(energy_k*t)
    
    re_psi = alpha*cos - eta*sin
    im_psi = eta*cos + alpha*sin
    psi = re_psi + im_psi

    return idst(psi)

Psi = Psi(2e-16)

plt.plot(xgrid,Psi)
plt.show()
```

I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: You are overriding the reference to the function *Psi* with *Psi = Psi(2e-16)*. You probably meant *psi = Psi(2e-16)*

Answer (score 1):

On the third-to-last line:

```
Psi = Psi(2e-16)
```

You are updating the reference to `Psi` from the function to the return value. Upon doing so, `Psi` can no longer be used as a function. It is advisory to never use variables with the same names as functions or classes in your code. Solutions are to either rename the variable, or rename the function and function call.

Comment: Oh, nice! Thank you guys.